# What configuration file should I modify to affect tramp configuration?

Tags: init-file, tramp, configuration-files

I am new to Emacs.
I run Linux. I'd like to tramp into a Windows machine, so that I can edit the files on the Windows machine from the comfort of my Linux system.
Apparently, you have to change the shell used by ssh on the Windows host for it to work.

I found pages that tell me how to do that with snippets of configuration here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Remote-shell-setup.html and so I would like to add this to tramp's configuration:

```el
(add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
    (list (regexp-quote "/sshx:windowsusername@windowshost:")
        "remote-shell" "git-bash.exe"))
```

But I have no idea in what file I should put this. I tried to create a `/home/username/.emacs.d/init.el` file and I wrote the snippet above inside that file. But that makes no change (the default shell `/bin/sh` is still used and that makes the tramp session fail). So I guess I'm not putting that snippet in the correct location.

I've searched for more general information about tramp configuration. This seems to be the main page, again, with examples of customization snippets: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Configuration.html

But where should they go?

Should I create an `init.el` file in `/home/username/.emacs.d` and add the tramp configuration directives there (that didn't seem to work) ? Or is there a tramp specific configuration file ? Or should I put this in `/home/username/.emacs` ? Or in a directory specific to tramp inside `/home/username/.emacs.d` ?

Comment: (FWIW, your `regexp-quote` isn't needed for the arg you give it here.)

Comment: start emacs after saving random text in your `init.el` and if it is loaded from the location, fatal error will occur.

Comment: The remote shell shall be an absolute path. "git-bash.exe" is a relative path only.

Comment: Yes, my question here was specifically about what config file to edit. It seems that modifying ~/.emacs.d/init.el has no effect but modifying ~/.emacs has an effect. For the question of how to specify the path, see my question here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77310/with-tramp-how-to-use-a-remote-shell-that-contains-spaces-in-the-path specifying the full path is tricky since it contains a space that is misinterpreted on the remote side.

Comment: Emacs looks for an init file in [various places](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html) and it uses the first one that it finds. So if you have both a `~/.emacs` and an `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, only the first one will ever be effective. You need to *delete* the first one in order for Emacs to use the second one  - and so on down the line. You can ask Emacs what init file it is using to make sure: `C-h v user-init-file`.

Comment: Thank you, that explains why modifying `init.el` didn't do anything. And there's never a configuration file per package? Such as a configuration file for tramp for example? I think I saw mention of a `tramp.el` file somewhere on the internet.

Comment: I think that might make it easier to configure things if one configuration file per package was really a possibility offered by emacs.

Comment: Nothing stops you: I have many config files and my `init.el` is pretty much a list of `require`s of those config files. OTOH, `tramp.el` is not a configuration file for `tramp`: it's the top level code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification: tramp.el is actually the file containing the code of the package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an MS Windows machine from Linux via Tramp, you're better with the `smb` method. This doesn't need any remote shell.

Comment: Will I be able to use the C# language server with eglot that way? I would guess this requires ssh access, not just file access.

Comment: No. The `smb` method doesn't support remote processes.